# Interview : Hash function: sine function

Tags: c, trigonometry

I was asked this interview question. I am not sure what the correct answer for it is (and the reasoning behind the answer):

Is sin(x) a good hash function?

Comment: No, it's not. It's actually a very bad hash function as are all periodic functions...

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan Wouldn't that depend on what you're hashing? Surely using sin on integers (well at least if unsigned) gives unique results.

Comment: What is `sine()`? The C standard only defines `sin()` but not `sine()`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: ok..corrected.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze No need to be condescending, if you made the comment you obviously know what was meant, you have more than enough rep to go in and change it if you so desire.  Otherwise technically the word SINE is the correct mathematical term for the sin() function in C.  The terms are analogous......

Comment: @Armen: it's not. sin(n) behaves as random for large integers.

Comment: @agentx: please edit title too.

Comment: @Alexandre C. "sin(n) --> random for large integers"  in some `sin(x)` encodings, may exhibit total loss of precision, hence random results.  Although C does not specify precision, good sin(x) implementations exist that provide precise answers for _all_ x.  Google K.C. Ng's "Good to the Last Bit".

Comment: @chux: Good to know. Thanks! Do you happen to know where this is implemented today (apart from the Sun libm, as told in the article)?

Comment: @Alexandre C. Sorry, no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean `sin()`, it's not a good hashing function because:

- it's quite predictable and for some `x` it's no better than just `x` itself. There should be no seemingly apparent relationship between the key and the hash of the key.
- it does not produce an integer value. You cannot index/subscript arrays with floating-point indices and there must be some kind of array in the hash table.
- floating-point is very implementation-specific and even if you make a hash function out of `sin()`, it may not work with a different compiler or on a different kind of CPU/computer.
- `sin()` may be much slower than some simpler integer-arithmetic function.

Comment: why is predictability a bad thing?

Comment: @stefan You want to avoid collisions and have a nearly even distribution of hash values w.r.t. keys. With very simple (predictable) hash functions, you are very likely to produce noticeably skewed distributions and run into collisions, both of which degrade the performance of the hash table.

Comment: @stefan: [Hash table implementations vulnerable to algorithmic complexity attacks](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/903934) presents one instance where predictability could be a disadvantage in a hash function.

Comment: I disagree. Surely hashs with collission are really bad, but it's not the predictability that causes this issue, it's the periodic behaviour of sin/cos. Define _predictability_ ;-)

Comment: @stefan Perhaps it's not the best wording. The quality of a hash function is not determined by the hash function alone, it's determined in the context, by the input. `sin(x)` adapted for hashing may work fine if `x` itself is rather random, despite the periodicity of `sin(x)`.

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

1. It's horribly slow.
2. You'll need to convert the result to some integer type anyway to avoid the insanity of floating-point equality comparisons.  (Not actually the *usual* precision problems that are endemic to FP equality comparisons and which arise from calculating two things slightly different ways; I mean specifically the problems caused by things like the fact that 387-derived FPUs store extra bits of precision in their registers, so if a comparison is done between two freshly-calculated values in registers you could get a different answer than if exactly one of the operands was loaded into a register from memory.)
3. It's almost flat near the peaks and troughs, so the quantisation step (multiplying by some large number and rounding to an integer) will produce many hash values near the min and max, rather than an even distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of mathematical knowledge:

Sine(x) is periodic so it's going to reach the same number from different values of x, so Sine(x) would be awful as a hashing function because you will get multiple values hashing to the exact same point.  There are **infinitely many values between 0 and pi for the return value, but then past that the values will repeat.  So 0 & pi & 2*pi will all hash to the same point.

If you could make the increment small enough and have Sine(x) multiplied by say x^2 or something of that nature it'd be mediocre at best, but then again, if you were to do that why not just use x^2 anyway and toss out the periodic function all together.

**infinitely: a large enough number that I'm not willing to count.

NOTE: Sine(x) will have values that are small and could be affected by rounding error.

NOTE: Any value taken from a sine function should be multiplied by an integer and then either modded or the floor or ceiling taken so that the value can be used as an array offset, etc.

Comment: Well, the periodicity problem doesn't arise when it's applied to individual bytes.

Comment: "0 & pi & 2*pi" all hash to the same?  Algebraically yes, but every computer language I've used so far has only approximated pi resulting in sin(0) != sin(about_pi) != sin(2*about_pi).

Answer (score 1):

`sin(x)` is trigonometric function which repeats itself after every 360 degrees, so it's going to be a poor hash function as the hash will be repeated too often.

A simple refutation:

```
sin(0) == sin(360) == sin(720) == sin(..)
```

This is not a property of a goodhash function.

Even if you decide to use it, it's difficult to represent the value returned by sin.
Sin function:

```
sin x = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! - ...
```

This can't accurately represented due to floating point precision issue, which means for a same value it may produce two different hashes!

Comment: Well, this problem doesn't arise when it's applied to individual bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Another point to note:

For sine(x) as hash function - Keys in a given close range will have hash values in close range too, it is not desirable. A good hash function evenly distributes hash values irrespective of the nature of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Hash values generally have to be integers to be useful. Since `sin` doesn't generate integers it wouldn't be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have a string s. It can be expressed as a number in hexadecimal and feeded to the function. If you added 2 pi it would cease to be a valid input, as it wouldn't be an integer anymore (only non-negative integers are accepted by the function). You have to find a string that gives a collision, not just multiply the hex expression of the string with 2 pi. And adding (concatenating?) 2 pi directly to the string wouldn't help finding a collision. There might be another way though but not that trivial.

Answer (score -1):

I think sin(x) can make an excellent cryptographic hash function,
if used wisely. The input should be a natural number in radians
and never contain pi. We must use arbitrary-precision arithmetic.
For every natural number x (radians), sin(x)
is always a transcendental irrational number and there is no other
natural number with the same sine. But there's a catch: An attacker could gain
information about the input, by computing the arcsin of the hash.
In order to prevent this, we ignore the decimal part and some of the
first digits from the fractional part, keeping only the next n (say 100) digits,
making such an attack computationally infeasible.
It seems that a small change in the input gives a completely different result,
which is a desirable property.
The result of the function seems statistically random, again a good property.
I'm not sure how to prove that is is collision-resistant but i can't see why
it couldn't be. Also, i can't think of a way to find a specific input that results
in a specific hash. I'm not saying that we should blindly believe that it is
certainly a good crypt. hash function. I just think that it seems like a
good candidate to be one. We should give it a chance
and focus on proving that it is. And it might me a very good one.
To those that might say it is slow: Yes, it is. And that's good when hashing passwords.
Here i'm attaching some perl code for this idea. It runs on linux with bash and bc.
(bc is a command-line arbitrary-precision calculator, included in most distros)
I'll be checking this page for any answers, since this interests me a lot.
Don't be harsh though, i'm just a CS undergrad, willing to learn more.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
my $input='5AFF36B7';#Input for bc (as a hex number)
$input='1'.$input;#put '1' in front of input, so that 0x0 , 0x00 , 0x1 , 0x01 , etc ... ,
                  #all give different nonzero results

my $a=`bc -l -q <<< "scale=256;obase=16;ibase=16;s($input)"`;#call bc, keep result in $a

#keep only fractional part
$a=~tr/a-zA-Z0-9//cd;#Clean up string, keep only alphanumerics
my @m = $a =~ /./g;#Convert string to array of chars

#PRINT OUTPUT
#We ignore some digits, for security reasons:
#If we don't ignore any of the first digits, an attacker could gain information
#about the input by computing the inverse of sin (the arcsin of the hash)
#By ignoring enough of the first digits, it becomes computationally
#infeasible to compute arcsin
#Also, to avoid problems with roundoff error, we ignore some of the last digits
for (my $c=100;$c<200;$c++){
    print $m[$c];
}
```

Comment: It's vulnerable to collision quite trivially: add 2 pi to the plaintext and boom, hash broken